# Wrap a string in tags using text manipulation in a Unix environment

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a text file that outputs as below:

```
    /usr/local/jack/var/12345/configs/10.254.254.254
    1845:    edit "n_10.73.6.0/24"
    1847:        set subnet 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0
    2161:        set member "n_10.73.8.0/24" "n_10.73.1.0/24" "n_10.73.2.0/24" "n_10.73.3.0/24" "n_10.73.4.0/24" "n_10.73.5.0/24" "n_10.73.6.0/24" "n_10.73.7.0/24" "n_10.73.9.0/24"
    7030:        set dst 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0

    /usr/local/jack/var/12346/configs/10.254.254.255
    1845:    edit "n_10.73.6.0/24"
    1847:        set subnet 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0
    2161:        set member "n_10.73.8.0/24" "n_10.73.1.0/24" "n_10.73.2.0/24" "n_10.73.3.0/24" "n_10.73.4.0/24" "n_10.73.5.0/24" "n_10.73.6.0/24" "n_10.73.7.0/24" "n_10.73.9.0/24"
    7030:        set dst 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0
    8 matches
    2 files contained matches
    931 files searched
    31258200 bytes searched
    0.056300 seconds
    logout
```

I want to be able to turn the file path into a hyperlink based on the file path itself. For example:

```
/usr/local/jack/var/12346/configs/10.254.254.255
```

would become:

```
<a href="http://jack.localnet/viewvc/12345/configs/10.254.254.255?view=markup">/usr/local/jack/var/12346/configs/10.254.254.255</a>
```

There could be 1,2 or hundreds of occurrences within this file. I want to make it so each occurrence will be replaced with a hyperlink.

Is this something that is possible with bash, sed, awk, python or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's,^\(/usr/local/jack/var/[0-9]*\)\(/.*\)$,<a href="http://jack.localnet/viewvc/12345\2?view=markup">\1\2</a>,g' file.txt
```

add `-i` if you want to replace the content of the file directly (but you need to be sure that the command is working fine). Safer, you can do :

```
sed 's,^\(/usr/local/jack/var/[0-9]*\)\(/.*\)$,<a href="http://jack.localnet/viewvc/12345\2?view=markup">\1\2</a>,g' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Result :

```
<a href="http://jack.localnet/viewvc/12345/configs/10.254.254.254?view=markup">/usr/local/jack/var/12345/configs/10.254.254.254</a>
1845:    edit "n_10.73.6.0/24"
1847:        set subnet 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0
2161:        set member "n_10.73.8.0/24" "n_10.73.1.0/24" "n_10.73.2.0/24" "n_10.73.3.0/24" "n_10.73.4.0/24" "n_10.73.5.0/24" "n_10.73.6.0/24" "n_10.73.7.0/24" "n_10.73.9.0/24"
7030:        set dst 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0

<a href="http://jack.localnet/viewvc/12345/configs/10.254.254.255?view=markup">/usr/local/jack/var/12346/configs/10.254.254.255</a>
1845:    edit "n_10.73.6.0/24"
1847:        set subnet 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0
2161:        set member "n_10.73.8.0/24" "n_10.73.1.0/24" "n_10.73.2.0/24" "n_10.73.3.0/24" "n_10.73.4.0/24" "n_10.73.5.0/24" "n_10.73.6.0/24" "n_10.73.7.0/24" "n_10.73.9.0/24"
7030:        set dst 10.73.6.0 255.255.255.0
8 matches
2 files contained matches
931 files searched
31258200 bytes searched
0.056300 seconds
logout
```

is it normal if 12346 becomes 12345 ?

Comment: That works nearly perfectly! Do you know how I can get the URL in it as well as mentioned in the first post? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jaaacck I edited and added the result I got and think that it does what you want already, do you have an other ouput ?

Comment: @Coretin Limier - the hyperlink should look like: <a href="http://jack.localnet/viewvc/12345/configs/10.254.254.254">/usr/local/jack/var/12345/configs/10.254.254.254</a>"

Is this possible to do while keeping the hyperlink name the same as the original file path?

Comment: sorry to be picky... but It needs to match this format:

`<a href="jack.localnet/viewvc/12345/configs/10.254.254.254">/usr/local/jack/var/12346/configs/10.254.254.255</a>`

The formatting of the URL is slightly different to the hyperlink name

Comment: @jaaacck I don't get it, what is the issue here ? the `http://` or `10.254.254.255` . + the format you give me in comment is not the same as in the initial question

Comment: Apologies, your original comment had updated at that time.

The number also changes as well, so 12345/12346 will depend on the file path

Comment: `sed -i 's,^\(/usr/local/jack/var\)\([0-9]*\)\(/.*\)$,<hr><h4><a href="http://jack.localnet/viewvc\2\3?view=markup">\1\3</a></h4>,g'`


This was the answer - thanks for the help, Corentin.